# `insertAdjacentHTML` and `createElement`

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How can I keep a reference to a newly created element (`createElement()`), that I inserted after an existing element in the DOM (`insertAdjacentHTML()`)?

In this example, you can see that the color doesn't change, if I use `elNew`/`elNewInner` after `insertAdjacentHTML()`:

```js
var elOrig = document.getElementById('insertAfter');

// Create new element
var elNew = document.createElement('div'),
  elNewInner = document.createElement('div');

elNewInner.textContent = 'I\'m a new element, but I\'m not red';

elNew.appendChild(elNewInner);

elOrig.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', elNew.outerHTML);

// This doesn't change the color in the DOM
elNewInner.style.color = 'red';
```

```html
<div id="insertAfter">Insert new element after me</div>
```

Is there any way to keep an reference to an element after I use `insertAdjacentHTML` or are there other ways in JavaScript to achieve the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better approach than using `.insertAdjacentHTML` with `.outerHTML` like that would be to use `.insertBefore` from the `.parentNode` of `elOrig`.

```js
var elOrig = document.getElementById('insertAfter');

// Create new element
var elNew = document.createElement('div'),
  elNewInner = document.createElement('div');

elNewInner.textContent = 'I\'m a new element, but I\'m not red';

elNew.appendChild(elNewInner);
elOrig.parentNode.insertBefore(elNew, elOrig.nextSibling)

// This doesn't change the color in the DOM
elNewInner.style.color = 'red';
```

```html
<div id="insertAfter">Insert new element after me</div>
```

This inserts `elNew` before the `.nextSibling` of `elOrig`, which is effectively the same as putting it `"afterend"` using `insertAdjacentHTML`.

With your original way, you were taking the new elements, converting it to HTML then making new elements from that HTML, which is certainly going to be slower, and is ultimately appending a copy.

Comment: This only answers half of the question _are there other ways in JavaScript to achieve the same?_. I'm interested in why that does not work

Comment: @Tushar: Read the last sentence. It shows why the original way didn't work.